# The type initializer for '' threw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Consider this code:

```
public class CountEnum : EnumDataType
    {
        public static readonly CountEnum CANADA = new CountEnum("CA", "Canada");
        public static readonly CountEnum DEFAULT = new CountEnum();
        private static readonly EnumDataTypeList OPTIONS = new EnumDataTypeList();
        public static readonly CountEnum UNITED_STATES = new CountEnum("US", "United States");
        public static readonly CountEnum UNSET = new CountEnum();


        private CountEnum()
        {
        }

        private CountEnum(string code, string name)
        {
            base.code = code;
            base.name = name;
            OPTIONS.Add(this); // This is the line 23
        }
```

Below are the exception details:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was caught
  Message=The type initializer for 'CP.BusinessLogic.VConfig' threw an exception.
  Source=CP.BusinessLogic
  TypeName=CP.BusinessLogic.VConfig
  StackTrace:
       at CP.BusinessLogic.VConfig.get_Instance()
       at CP.Fac.CPFac.GetActs() in C:\tfs_src\TeamProject\Main\Source\DApp\CPApp\Fac\CPFac.cs:line 170
  InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException
       Message=The type initializer for 'CP.Types.CountEnum' threw an exception.
       Source=CP.BusinessLogic
       TypeName=CP.Types.CountEnum
       StackTrace:
            at CP.BusinessLogic.VConfig..ctor() in C:\tfs_src\TeamProject\Main\Source\DApp\CPApp\BusinessLogic\VConfig.cs:line 14
            at CP.BusinessLogic.VConfig..cctor() in C:\tfs_src\TeamProject\Main\Source\DApp\CPApp\BusinessLogic\VConfig.cs:line 11
       InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
            Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            Source=CP.DataObject
            StackTrace:
                 at CP.Types.CountEnum..ctor(String code, String name) in C:\tfs_src\TeamProject\Main\Source\DApp\CPApp\Types\CountEnum.cs:line 23
                 at CP.Types.CountEnum..cctor() in C:\tfs_src\TeamProject\Main\Source\DApp\CPApp\Types\CountEnum.cs:line 8
            InnerException:
```

I am unable to figure out why I am getting this exception at runtime. I am not getting any build errors and the code looks correct.

Comment: You should include VConfig code.. at least the ctor and the getInstance func.

Comment: What's on line 23 of CountEnum? (It doesn't help that the code you've posted isn't actually valid C# to start with - `read only` should be `readonly`, for example. I strongly suspect your `CountEnum` constructor does *something* that relies on some state which hasn't been initialized.

Comment: @Pinu Because your static variable is not  assigned any value during compile time so you are not getting any error during build.Static variable value will be assigned at run time so you are getting error at runtime only .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by your stack trace, I think you've missed out the guilty code. For example, maybe it *actually* looks like this:

```
public class CountEnum
{
   public static readonly CountEnum DEFAULT = new CountEnum();
   private static readonly List<CountEnum> AllInstances = new List<CountEnum>();

   private CountEnum()
   {
       AllInstances.Add(this);
   }
}
```

That would behave the way the stack trace shows, with the `CountEnum` constructor throwing a `NullReferenceException`. However, we can't tell for sure as you haven't included the body of the `CountEnum` constructor (or indeed posted valid code for `CountEnum` at all).

Fundamentally though, this is the bit of the stack trace you should be looking at:

```
InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
     Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
     Source=CP.DataObject
     StackTrace:
          at CP.Types.CountEnum..ctor(String code, String name) in C:\...\CountEnum.cs:line 23
          at CP.Types.CountEnum..cctor() in C:\...\CountEnum.cs:line 8
```

You should be looking at line 23 of `CountEnum.cs` - that's what's throwing the exception.

EDIT: Okay, now we can see the code in question, it's very similar to my guess. Look at this code:

```
public static readonly CountEnum CANADA = new CountEnum("CA", "Canada");
public static readonly CountEnum DEFAULT = new CountEnum();
private static readonly EnumDataTypeList OPTIONS = new EnumDataTypeList();
```

These variables will be initialized in the order you've specified - so the call to `CountEnum("CA", "Canada")` will execute before `OPTIONS` has a non-null value... and when you try to add it to `OPTIONS`, you'll get an exception in a perfectly normal way.

You *can* fix this just by moving the declaration of `OPTIONS` to the top:

```
private static readonly EnumDataTypeList OPTIONS = new EnumDataTypeList();
public static readonly CountEnum CANADA = new CountEnum("CA", "Canada");
public static readonly CountEnum DEFAULT = new CountEnum();
```

That's guaranteed to work, but it's a fairly brittle design. I *have* used designs like this in the past, but you can get into fiddly messes when you require a particular initialization order.

Comment: private CountEnum(string code, string name)
        {
            base.code = code;
            base.name = name;
            OPTIONS.Add(this);  // this is the line 23
        }

Comment: @Pinu: And what is `OPTIONS`? My guess is that the value is a null reference at this point... (You should edit your *question* to show what the relevant parts of `CountEnum` actually look like, by the way. It's crazy for us to have to play 20 questions with you to get all the relevant information.)

Comment: Sorry not posting all the information. I had no clue as to where it was giving an error. I followed the debug break points and posted the code. I have updated the code above.

Comment: @Pinu: You *did* have a clue about where the error was - the clue was right there in the stack trace! I've edited my answer, but you should take a step back and work out why you couldn't have diagnosed this yourself, and what you'd do differently next time.